# After installing an icon font, propertize still show unknown characters

Tags: fonts, faces, text-properties

I'm trying to use custom icons from https://materialdesignicons.com/.

```el
(defface mdi-face
  `((t (:family "Material Design Icons")))
  "Face for Material design icons.")

(insert (propertize "\f004" 'face 'mdi-face)))
```

The font is installed system-wide and is available to Emacs. All I see is a sequence of little squares as if the font wasn't installed.

Comment: It seems I should escape with the hexadecimal character `\xf004`. However that specific example gives me a heart instead of a `mdi-account`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```el
(insert (propertize "\xf004" 'face 'mdi-face)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've resolved the problem or not.  FWIW, I ran into what you mentioned as your second problem (characters not showing up correctly in spite of using proper hexadecimal) a while ago.  I noticed this when adding material icons to all-the-icons.el:

From https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el/pull/35 :

> Note that at the font package version on Debian (1.4.57) has different
>   unicode mappings that the current version that I have included
>   (3.0.1). Icons may not render correctly if a user has an outdated
>   version of the material design icons font. I haven't checked into when
>   this mapping shifted.

If you have a version incongruent with the documentation you are referring to some characters will render as an unexpected character and some will render as tofu ([]).

Comment: Thanks for the details. However, I had a completely different problem (a silly one at that). When trying to insert a specific icon from `mdi`, another completely different icon would show up. I still had an old `(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#xf000 . #xffff) "Font Awesome")` in effect. Add to that, that the escape was done incorrectly like in the question (missing the `x`).